# How to refactor a react sign in component into an existing material ui sign in component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, material-ui, refactoring

My goal is to refactor my existing sign-in page into a material UI sign in page.

Below is my existing sign-in component that is titled "Navbar.js". As you can see state is managed within this file, as well as an axios call to an SQL db/user authentication/etc...

My goal is to refactor this existing login page code into a material UI login page that I found. I am fairly new to react (state) and material UI so any help is greatly appreciated! If I can provide any more material or reorganize it so that it is easier to approach feel free to let me know. Thanks!

**Navbar.js (my existing login page)**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

async function attemptLogin(un, pw, setSignedIn, signedIn) {
  try {
    if (signedIn) {
      window.localStorage.setItem("jwt", "");
      setSignedIn(false);
      return;
    }

    const response = await axios.post("http://localhost:4000/login", {
      username: un,
      password: pw,
    });
    console.log(response);
    if (response.data.jwt) {
      setSignedIn(true);
      window.localStorage.setItem("jwt", response.data.jwt);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
export default function Navbar({
  signedIn,
  setSignedIn,
  setAllPlaylists,
  allPlaylists,
  fetchPlaylists,
}) {
  const defaultValue = {
    un: "",
    pw: "",
  };
  const [signInForm, setSignInForm] = useState(defaultValue);

  return (
    <>
      Username:
      <input
        value={signInForm.un}
        onChange={(event) =>
          setSignInForm({ ...signInForm, un: event.target.value })
        }
      />
      Password:
      <input
        value={signInForm.pw}
        onChange={(event) =>
          setSignInForm({ ...signInForm, pw: event.target.value })
        }
        type="password"
      />
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          attemptLogin(signInForm.un, signInForm.pw, setSignedIn, signedIn);
          setSignInForm({ ...defaultValue });
        }}
      >
        {signedIn ? "Sign Out" : "Sign In"}
      </button>
      <button onClick={fetchPlaylists}>
        {!allPlaylists ? "Show only my playlists" : "Show all playlists"}
      </button>
    </>
  );
}
```

**SignIn.js (a new file which contains a material UI login layout)**

```
import React from "react";
import Avatar from "@material-ui/core/Avatar";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import CssBaseline from "@material-ui/core/CssBaseline";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import FormControlLabel from "@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel";
import Checkbox from "@material-ui/core/Checkbox";
import Link from "@material-ui/core/Link";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import Box from "@material-ui/core/Box";
import LockOutlinedIcon from "@material-ui/icons/LockOutlined";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Container from "@material-ui/core/Container";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  paper: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(8),
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  avatar: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1),
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.main,
  },
  form: {
    width: "100%", // Fix IE 11 issue.
    marginTop: theme.spacing(1),
  },
  submit: {
    margin: theme.spacing(3, 0, 2),
  },
}));

export default function SignIn() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Container component="main" maxWidth="xs">
      <CssBaseline />
      <div className={classes.paper}>
        <Avatar className={classes.avatar}>
          <LockOutlinedIcon />
        </Avatar>
        <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
          Sign in
        </Typography>
        <form className={classes.form} noValidate>
          <TextField
            variant="outlined"
            margin="normal"
            required
            fullWidth
            id="email"
            label="Username"
            name="username"
            autoComplete="username"
            autoFocus
          />
          <TextField
            variant="outlined"
            margin="normal"
            required
            fullWidth
            name="password"
            label="Password"
            type="password"
            id="password"
            autoComplete="current-password"
          />
          <FormControlLabel
            control={<Checkbox value="remember" color="primary" />}
            label="Remember me"
          />
          <Button
            type="submit"
            fullWidth
            variant="contained"
            color="primary"
            className={classes.submit}
          >
            Sign In
          </Button>
          <Grid container>
            {/* <Grid item xs>
              <Link href="#" variant="body2">
                Forgot password?
              </Link>
            </Grid> */}
            <Grid item>
              <Link href="#" variant="body2">
                {"Don't have an account? Sign Up"}
              </Link>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </form>
      </div>
      <Box mt={8}>
        <Copyright />
      </Box>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

Comment: It would be great if you could share a sandbox.

Comment: Hi - I just tried to put these two pieces into a sandbox. I had to remove many other pieces that are part of the app but tried to keep the existing Navbar.js (existing login setup) and Signin.js (new material ui login template that I want to refactor into). thanks! @urvashi https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-sara-6647e?file=/src/components/Signin.js

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

A Bit difficult to test with incomplete code. I tried my best to refactor it. It can be refactored more. Have updated the sandbox as well.

```
    import React, { useState } from "react";
    import axios from "axios";
    import Avatar from "@material-ui/core/Avatar";
    import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
    import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
    import FormControlLabel from "@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel";
    import Checkbox from "@material-ui/core/Checkbox";
    import Link from "@material-ui/core/Link";
    import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
    // import Box from "@material-ui/core/Box";
    import LockOutlinedIcon from "@material-ui/icons/LockOutlined";
    import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
    import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
    import Container from "@material-ui/core/Container";
    
    const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
      paper: {
        marginTop: theme.spacing(8),
        display: "flex",
        flexDirection: "column",
        alignItems: "center"
      },
      avatar: {
        margin: theme.spacing(1),
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.main
      },
      form: {
        width: "100%", // Fix IE 11 issue.
        marginTop: theme.spacing(1)
      },
      submit: {
        margin: theme.spacing(3, 0, 2)
      }
    }));
    
    async function attemptLogin(un, pw, setSignedIn, signedIn) {
      try {
        if (signedIn) {
          window.localStorage.setItem("jwt", "");
          setSignedIn(false);
          return;
        }
    
        const response = await axios.post("http://localhost:4000/login", {
          username: un,
          password: pw
        });
        console.log(response);
        if (response.data.jwt) {
          setSignedIn(true);
          window.localStorage.setItem("jwt", response.data.jwt);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    }
    
    export default function SignIn({
      signedIn,
      setSignedIn,
      setAllPlaylists,
      allPlaylists,
      fetchPlaylists
    }) {
      const classes = useStyles();
      const defaultValue = {
        un: "",
        pw: ""
      };
      const [signInForm, setSignInForm] = useState(defaultValue);
      return (
        <Container component="main" maxWidth="xs">
          <div className={classes.paper}>
            <Avatar className={classes.avatar}>
              <LockOutlinedIcon />
            </Avatar>
            <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
              Sign in
            </Typography>
            <form className={classes.form} noValidate>
              <TextField
                variant="outlined"
                margin="normal"
                required
                fullWidth
                id="email"
                label="Username"
                name="username"
                autoComplete="username"
                autoFocus
                value={signInForm.un}
                onChange={(event) =>
                  setSignInForm({ ...signInForm, un: event.target.value })
                }
              />
              <TextField
                variant="outlined"
                margin="normal"
                required
                fullWidth
                name="password"
                label="Password"
                type="password"
                id="password"
                autoComplete="current-password"
                value={signInForm.pw}
                onChange={(event) =>
                  setSignInForm({ ...signInForm, pw: event.target.value })
                }
              />
              <FormControlLabel
                control={<Checkbox value="remember" color="primary" />}
                label="Remember me"
              />
              <Button
                type="submit"
                fullWidth
                variant="contained"
                color="primary"
                className={classes.submit}
                onClick={() => {
                  attemptLogin(signInForm.un, signInForm.pw, setSignedIn, signedIn);
                  setSignInForm({ ...defaultValue });
                }}
              >
                {signedIn ? "Sign Out" : "Sign In"}
              </Button>
              <Grid container>
                {/* <Grid item xs>
                  <Link href="#" variant="body2">
                    Forgot password?
                  </Link>
                </Grid> */}
                <Grid item>
                  <Link href="#" variant="body2">
                    {"Don't have an account? Sign Up"}
                  </Link>
                </Grid>
              </Grid>
            </form>
          </div>
        </Container>
      );
    }
```